# Weird behaviour of getParcelableExtra (Key X expected Parcelable but value was a Y)

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

Can someone explain why this code doesn't work?

```java
Intent i = new Intent(this.context, SomeClass.class);
HashMap<String, String> tmp1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
Log.d(TAG, "IN: " + String.valueOf(tmp1));
i.putExtra("VAR", tmp1);
HashMap<String, String> tmp2 = i.getParcelableExtra("VAR");
Log.d(TAG, "OUT: " + String.valueOf(tmp2));
```

What I expect to get:

- HashMap **is** parcellable. `tmp1` should equal `tmp2`.

What I actually get (LogCat):

- *Debug:* **IN: {}**
- *Warning:* Key `VAR` expected `Parcelable` but value was a `java.util.HashMap`. The default value `<null>` was returned.
- *Warning:* Attempt to cast generated internal exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap`
- *Debug:* **OUT: null**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mistaken, `HashMap` is *not* `Parcelable`. It is however `Serializable`, so you are putting a `Serializable` extra and trying to read it as a `Parcelable`, which causes the error.